# What does the word 지방근무 mean?

Tags: word-usage

What does 지방근무 가능 mean? I found it in research-related job requirement. Is it similar to 잡무? Is there any negative meaning in this word? Dictionary suggests "fat" and "area" for 지방, but its sounds more like "be ready for routine work at first".

Comment: probably means you are allowed to work outside the city, most likely Seoul

Comment: please add more details or context if possible. This does not mean "fat", this is area outside metropolis, usually Seoul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

지방 is a homonym.
지방(脂肪) means fat, but in your context 지방 is 지방(地方) which means outside of Seoul Metropolitan Area.

지방근무 가능 in the job requirement means that you should be able to work outside of Seoul Metropolitan Area. It means that if you live in Seoul or Gyeonggi, then you may have to relocate.

잡무 means miscellaneous or trivial work.

Answer (score 2):

As @user17915 mentioned, 지방 means rural areas or smaller towns, usually outside of Seoul. Hence 지방근무 가능 suggests you are not work in large cities if you take it, but, 지방근무 가능 could have a different meaning by context.

If you are seeking physical work, then it usually means the workplace is in rural areas, possibly very far from cities (even from smaller ones.) If it is not the case, 지방 could mean just outside Seoul Metropolitan, even including Busan, Gwangju, or Daejeon (although larger cities are less likely.) You may google the companies you are seeking to see where they placed in.

Answer (score 2):

It generally means anywhere outside of Seoul.

The reason the company asks this is because Seoul is the most convenient city to live in.